# Is it justified that ESA is pushing to launch Rosalind Franklin even after Schiaparelli landing failed?

Tags: mars, esa, exomars, schiaparelli-lander

As far as I am aware, ESA has not achieved a successful martian landing yet. Why is it still a good idea to try with full-scale rover, weighting more than Opportunity and Spirit (though less than Curiosity, which indeed had huge landing experience to build on - unlike Rosalind Franklin).

Comment: I'm voting to close this as opinion based, it's also very broad. All I will say is if you don't try, you don't succeed, where would space exploration be if we quit after a couple of tries?

Comment: NASA didn't go to Curiosity straight after the Vikings. There is room between trying to land a heavier-than Spirit rover and not doing anything at all. The question did not propose quitting exploration.

Comment: Edited the Q to make it less opinion-based, I hope this is better now

Comment: @zabop the edit helps a bit. Hint for the future; asking a little bit differently can result in a better received question and more thorough answers. For example, if you asked "What lessons were learned and steps taken by ESA following the Schiaparelli landing failure to improve the chances of Rosalind Franklin's successful landing?" or "Was there any pressure for ESA to delay ExoMars because..." These questions would not involve opinion-based answers.

Comment: Good points raised, will try to follow them.

Comment: ESA successfully landed Beagle II. Unfortunately it failed to deploy.

Comment: @JCRM Beagle 2 was not ESA, and it was not successful.

Comment: @MarkAdler It was a successful landing: "analysis of pictures of the Beagle 2 spacecraft shows that it did not crash-land on the Martian surface.

Instead, it indicates that the landing went to plan and at least three of its four solar panels opened successfully.

[...] the probe may even have worked for several months, but was unable to send its data back to Earth."

Beagle 2 was selected by the ESA’s Science 
Programme Committee, and developed by a UK (a member state of ESA) consortium. ESA became a major partner in Beagle 2 in late 2000, and technical adviser in mid 2001

Comment: @JCRM I am fully aware of the images taken by MRO and the wishful positive spin put on the attempt based on those images. However if there is no data from the lander after impact, then it was not a successful landing. (Even if there is data, but the mission cannot be conducted due to the impact, then that would also not be a successful landing.) I would acknowledge that ESA had some involvement, and so their engineering arm did get some learnings from the development.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Schiaparelli was a [test mission](https://www.theguardian.com/science/across-the-universe/live/2016/oct/19/mars-landing-esa-attempts-to-set-schiaparelli-probe-on-red-planet-live). During its descent, it [recorded and sent lots of data](https://www.nasaspaceflight.com/2016/10/schiaparelli-landing-data-exomars-2020-rover/) which was [analyzed](https://phys.org/news/2017-05-schiaparelli.html) and gave ESA the information it needed to proceed with the Rosalind Franklin mission.